# How do I implement Drop for a struct with an AtomicUsize field?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a crude instance counter but the issue I ran into is more general. I found I couldn't implement `Drop` for a struct containing an `AtomicUsize` field. Here's what I'm seeing:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

#[allow(non_upper_case_globals)]
static MyStruct_instance_counter: AtomicUsize = AtomicUsize::new(0);

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyStruct {
    id: u128,
    counter: AtomicUsize,
}
impl MyStruct {
    fn new(id: u128) -> Self {
        MyStruct_instance_counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        Self {
            id,
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for MyStruct {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        MyStruct_instance_counter.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `MyStruct`, which implements the `Drop` trait
  --> src/lib.rs:14:9
   |
14 | /         Self {
15 | |             id,
16 | |             ..Default::default()
17 | |         }
   | |         ^
   | |         |
   | |_________cannot move out of here
   |           move occurs because value has type `std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

While the error makes sense, I'm unsure how to address it. Is it not possible to implement `Drop` for any struct containing a field which does not implement the `Copy` trait? What can I do instead to track construction/destruction? In the grand scheme of things, I'd like to track reference counted objects to ensure they don't linger as a result of a circularity.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was the use of `Default` which is causing the problem. Although, now I'm unsure how to address that.

Comment: It's not `Default`, it's because you are moving fields out of a type that implements `Drop`. You do that with the struct update syntax `..some_value`. You just happen to be using `Default::Default()` as `some_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `..` here is called "struct update syntax" some places and ["functional update syntax"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html) in the rust language reference.  The reference says that it "moves or copies the remaining fields from the base expression".

I suspect that because the struct uses a custom `Drop` implementation, individual fields may not be moved out of it. Since `AtomicUsize` does not implement `Copy`, that leads to the error.

You may also have problem with the derived `Default` instance. It will not increment your main counter when it creates a new struct. You need to manually implement a `Default` to keep the creation count correct.